# How can I conduct the Legendre transformation of this problem?

Tags: legendre-transformation

> Consider the following function
> $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}-(a^2 - x^2)^{1/2} & \text{if }|x|\leq a  \\+ \infty &\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
> and compute its [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation).

I solved the above questions, however, I can't solve the question that the infinite in the function. How can I apply the Legendre transform to this question?

Comment: Hint : The legendre transform is defined by $f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb R}xx^* - f(x)$. Since $-f(x) = -\infty$ for $x\notin[-a,a]$ you have : $$f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x\in[-a,a]} xx^* - f(x)$$ From which point you can do the usual calculations to find $f^*$